# ajaxLink in layout has conflict with ajaxLink in view of actions

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, hyperlink

i use of ajaxLink in my view code, the ajaxLink that is in action views work nice but when i put ajaxLink in layout it don`t work.

i saw the executed code and understood there isn`t javascript code for layout ajaxLink!!
i think there is a conflict !!

ajax link code :

```
<?php echo $this->ajaxLink("change password",
                          $this->url(array("module"=>"admin" , "controller" => "user" , "ajax" => "on" ,"action" => "changepass"), "" ,false , false),
                          array('update' => '#container',
                                'method' => 'GET',
                                'beforeSend' => 'showLoadingImage();',
                                 'complete' => 'hideLoadingImage();')); ?>
```

this code creating automatically for every link but this code didn`t create for ajaxlink in layout! :

```
$('a.ajaxLink1').click(function() { showLoadingImage();$.get('/donyaye_fan_zend/public/admin/link/index/ajax/on', {}, function(data, textStatus) { $('#container').html(data); hideLoadingImage(); }, 'html');return false; });
```

what`s wrong?

Comment: to help you'll need to provide some code

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file (`layout.phtml`) place line : `<?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?>` just before `</body>` tag, **not** between `<head>...</head>` tags.

The layout file should look like this:

```
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
  <div id="some_div>
    ...
  </div>
  <?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?> // <-- add this line here not in <head> section
</body>
```

Comment: You should also enable jQuery before echoing it.

Place in layout.phtml:

<?php $this->jQuery()->enable(); ?>

<?php $this->jQuery()->uiEnable(); ?>